# Messy regression - semlilog exponential function using $e$

Tags: exponential-function, regression

Bit of a mathophobe. I have fit a regression to some data on a semi-log plot, and the resulting equation of the function is:

$$ y = e ^ {log_{10}  x} + 1.024 $$

That seems overly messy and wrong to me, but I cannot figure out why (it's been a while since I did any proper maths, but something doesn't sit right with me)

Any input would be a great help!

Here's an image of the plot itself:

[Plot, R2=0.841](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ffj.jpg)

The fit curve works to reproduce the y variable in locations where only the x variable isn't present.

Comment: edits were for formatting - first time using mathjax

Comment: If you fit a straight line to your data then it is most likely that variables have been transformed from (letting $p=\log y$) from $p=x+\log 1.024$ which is a straight line of the form $y=mx + c$ with $c=\log 1.024$ and $m=1$.

Comment: Kevin I've uploaded an image to help clarify what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at your image and the blue curve seems to fit $f(x)=y=0.6+0.4 \;x^{1/ln(10)}.\;$Note that $\;e ^ {log_{10}  x}=x^{1/ln(10)}$. The two constants can be adjusted for better fit. My fitted function gives $\;(x,f(x))\;$ data points $(1,1),(10,1.7),(100,3.6),(400,6)\;$ which you can compare to your data.

Comment: Yes this is what i was after, thanks a lot Somos! I've been away from the office today but will comment back on how things work out

Comment: Yep works great, curve-fitting in python I get coefficients of 0.397 and 0.617

Thanks once again